Not being able to use macro inside ODS
I'm using the following code:
ods package(ProdOutput) open nopf;
ods package(ProdOutput) add file='\\path(...)\20&year.M&month.\file.csv';

ods package(ProdOutput) publish archive
properties(archive_name='File 20&year.M&month..zip'
archive_path='\\path(...)\20&year.M&month.');

ods package(ProdOutput) close;

If I don't use the macro the ods function works just fine, but when I use the macro 20&year.M&month. the system doesn't recognize even though I'm using in other parts of the code and works just fine.

Text within single quotes does not resolve macro variables and functions. Use double-quotes instead:
ods package(ProdOutput) open nopf;
ods package(ProdOutput) add file="\\path(...)\20&year.M&month.\file.csv";

ods package(ProdOutput) publish archive
properties(archive_name="File 20&year.M&month..zip"
archive_path="\\path(...)\20&year.M&month.");

ods package(ProdOutput) close;


Apparently if I declare the macro as a global macro everything is ok.
